# Simple form not working

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, forms

I just have created custom form in Wordpress to add some comments fastly. 
I have write simple form:

```
<form method='post' method='xxxx.com/global/wp-content/themes/theme/autoblog/skryptkom.php'>
    <h3>Wpisz komentarze</h3>
     <p>
        <textarea name="komentarzex" rows="10" cols="30">
1 komentarz = 1 linia
        </textarea>
     </p>
    <h3>Wpisz nazwy uzytkowników</h3>
     <p>
        <textarea name="uzytkownicxy" rows="10" cols="30">
1 uyztkownik = 1 linia
        </textarea>
     </p>       
    <h3> Dodatkowe ustawienia</h3>
    Ile komentarzy musi mieć wpis aby dodało do niego dodatkowe komentarze: <input type="text" name="ilekomentarzy" value="0"><br>
    Do ilu wpisów dodack komantarze? : <input type="text" name="ileposotownaeraz" value="200"><br>
    Wpisz przedzial ile ma dodać komentarzy do wpisu : od <input type="text" name="odkoms" value="5"> do <input type="text" name="dokoms" value="20"><br>
      <p>
         <input type="submit" value="Dodaj komentarze" name="dodajmeykurwa" />
      </p>
</form>
```

And its display in admin page very good: http://prntscr.com/b3x3e3

But when I try to post comments its not working fine :(

Here is my code to do action:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['dodajmeykurwa'])) {
        require_once('spintax.php' );
        $komentarze = $_POST['komentarzex'];
        $uzytkownicy = $_POST['uzytkownicxy'];  

        $rakoms = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $komentarze);
        $rausers = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $uzytkownicy);

    require_once ('wp-blog-header.php');
    // ile koemntarzy musi miec post aby do niego dodac komentarz

    $ilekomsmusimiec = $_POST['ilekomentarzy']; 
    $limitdodanychpostow = $_POST['ileposotownaeraz'];  
    global $wpdb;
    // pobranie postów z liczbą komentarzy 0
    $posty = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, comment_count FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' AND comment_count= $ilekomsmusimiec ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $limitdodanychpostow");

    $spintax->process($string);

    if ($posty)
    {
        foreach ($posty as $p)
        {
            // losowe nicki i komentarze
            shuffle($rakoms);
            shuffle($rausers);
            $oidkoskoms = $_POST['odkoms']; 
            $dokadkoms = $_POST['dokoms'];  
            for ($i = $oidkoskoms, $size = $dokadkoms; $i < $size; $i++)
            {
                // ustawienia komentarza - wartości
                $data = array(
                    'comment_post_ID' => $p->id,
                    'comment_author' => $spintax->process($rausers[$i]),
                    'comment_author_email' => 'admin@admin.com',
                    'comment_author_url' => 'http://',
                    'comment_content' => $spintax->process($rakoms[$i]),
                    'comment_type' => '',
                    'comment_parent' => 0,
                    'user_id' => rand(1, 100),
                    'comment_author_IP' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'comment_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042316 Firefox/3.0.10 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)',
                    'comment_date' => current_time('mysql'),
                    'comment_approved' => 1,
                    );
                wp_insert_comment($data);
            }
        }
    } else
    {
        echo "Brak postow do ktorych mozna dodac komenatarze";
    }
}
?>
```

What I have do wrong?

Comment: _its not working fine_ - how so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicated method attribute on your form opening tag:

This:

```
<form method='post' method='xxxx.com/global/wp-content/themes/theme/autoblog/skryptkom.php'>
```

Should be:

```
<form method='post' action='xxxx.com/global/wp-content/themes/theme/autoblog/skryptkom.php'>
```

Comment: Hey, just have solve problem i think it was this issue, now i just put form and action code together.